# How to find a lifespan of a name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, timespan

I have a sql table containing a series of ids and dates that that id is registered in the system. One id can be registered several time. The table is like below :

```
ID           Date
3          16/6/2009 
4          2/4/2010
7          4/9/2012
3          12/6/2009
7          2/8/20011
3          16/12/2009
etc..
```

From a table like this I would like to extract the ids with their lifespan (I want to subtract the firstseen date and lastseen date).Ids can have same date and an id can be registered in different days.

Do anyone knows what query should I use to get the required result look like below?

```
ID               Date(week)
3               2/4/2009-16/6/2009
4                  2/4/2010
7               2/8/20011-4/9/2012
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT x.id
      , x.start 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT id
             , MIN(DATE) start 
          FROM my_table
         GROUP 
            BY id
      ) x 
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT id
             , MAX(DATE) end 
          FROM my_table
         GROUP
            BY id
      ) y 
     ON y.id = x.id 
    AND y.end > x.start;
```

Comment: Thanks. and Can you please tell me what is start?

Comment: It's an alias for MIN(date) - I'm assuming your dates use a DATE data type!